# User specified Orientation on Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I like that the user can specify the orientation of the Activity that it wants: LANDSCAPE or PORTRAIT.

My Activities are declared in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=“.ActivityA”
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

And in the onCreate method of the Activity I call

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int preferedOrientation = /* Code that get the prefered orientation */ 
    setRequestedOrientation(preferedOrientation);
    ... 
}
```

But when the user specifies LANDSCAPE, the activity first appears in PORTRAIT and then recreates to LANDSCAPE.

How this can be avoided?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` instead of `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"`

```
<activity
    android:name=“.ActivityA”
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

See [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

> **Caution:** Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
>   also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
>   orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
>   orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
>   declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
>   must include the "`screenSize`" value in addition to the "`orientation`"
>   value. That is, you must decalare
>   `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`. However, if your
>   application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
>   handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
>   does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
>   higher device).